Reduce the amount of time notification summaries appear onscreen on Apple Watch
I have the activated the "Show Summary When Locked" option on my Apple Watch. When I receive a notification, the app icon, title, and a brief summary appears onscreen when my wrist is down, and a more detailed notification appears if I tap on the screen or raise my wrist.
Sometimes, this brief summary remains present on my wrist for extended periods of time (what seems like at least a couple of minutes). This prevents me from reading the time without raising my wrist and dismissing the notification— a bother when, say, in a meeting.
Is it possible to reduce the amount of time this summary is displayed onscreen? Much to my surprise, I'm unable to find any such options in Settings, nor can I find any similar questions anywhere else online.

You can dismiss it immediately without raising your wrist by covering the watch screen, e.g. with your palm. I don't believe the time that the notification summary is shown for is customisable.
